# What's $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, inverse

What is $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$$ WolframAlpha says $\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{5})$ while I got $\frac{1}{5}\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{5})$. What is correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check by differentiating the two answers.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, WA is correct this time...plus a constant in both cases, of course.

Comment: For any standard integration problem (i.e. textbook for AP Calc and/or Calc 2), you can assume that WolframAlpha is more likely to be right than you are.

Comment: That's probably true, @anorton , "standard" being the gist here.

Comment: @anorton, you can also reasonably expect WA to be more accurate than the answer key of the textbook, given typesetting errors and such.

Comment: It seems that Wolfram Alpha worked 5 times harder, obtaining 5 times more. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

Substitute $x=5\sin\theta$ or $5\cos \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = 5u \to dx = 5du \to \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{25-x^2}} = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{5du}{\sqrt{25-25u^2}} = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} =\arcsin u + C = \arcsin \left(\frac{x}{5}\right) + C$